# I need dump table from SQL Server to csv in utf-8

Tags: sql-server, csv, utf-8, sqlcmd

This works but not in utf-8:

```
sqlcmd -S Server -d DB -E -s, -W -i "C:\Localdata\test.sql" | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > "C:\Localdata\Test.csv"
```

Would anybody like to help fix this into utf-8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `-u` switch for Unicode format output file.

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

add `-f 65001` to the sqlcmd command. (or `-f o:65001` if you want UTF-8 output, `-f i:65001` for UTF-8 input)

Answer (score 3):

type `chcp 65001` in the command line or batch file before calling sqlcmd

Answer (score 0):

But it's not UTF-8.

> sqlcmd automatically recognizes both big-endian and little-endian
> Unicode input files. If the -u option has been specified, the output
> will always be little-endian Unicode.

And thus, for instance, it disables using **diff** tool to compare output.

To overcome this M$ "comfort" with tool - use **iconv**:

```
iconv -t UTF-8 <sqlcmd.output.csv>
```

At Windows as "comfortable" М$ product again - you can use **iconv** from Git command line tool bundle, for instance.